# Cant connect to External IP

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to connect to my public IP http://34.125.119.106:8080/, where I have a Jenkins service running but I can't and don't know why.
I've create firewall rule to allow tcp traffic on port `8080`, which is the port exposed to Jenkins, but I still cannot connect. I looked into the `/etc/default/jenkins` file, to see if everything inside was configured correctly. I tried to line in this file like 'HTTP_HOST=127.0.0.1', like some people advise to do ,but it doesn't work for my case. Does anyone know how to solve this?
Sorry for my bad English.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqK0l.png)
i made a test and it successfully connected,but i still cant connect to my external Ip

Comment: nvm,i unistall vm and istall game with the same setting and all works.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step my recommendation is to check if your service is exposed and through what port number. For this you can use command `sudo netstat -plntu`. You should be looking for an output similar to:

`tcp6    0   0 :::8080   :::*     LISTEN    17917/java`

If its not, change your `/etc/default/jenkins` file to port 8080

After that from inside your GCP project, you can run a connectivity test having as `source` one of the IP addresses you are using to reach your Server and as `destination` your Servers VM instance IP address. This test will simulate traffic and tell you where it's getting stuck whether if it's stuck on the way to your Server or if your server is not correctly configured. You can get a good reference in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/network-intelligence-center/docs/connectivity-tests/how-to/running-connectivity-tests#non-cloud-to-vpc).

If you have already configured your ingress firewall rule, just make sure its applied to your VM, it sometimes happens that you have a network tag on your VM instance and another tag on your firewall rule.

Comment: i run the command you advising `sudo netstat -plntu` and i've got the line about you talking.What about test, i dont understand a little bit where i can find ip for destination.

Comment: You can do a connectivity test by entering the Network Intelligence menu on Cloud Console and selecting Connectivity Tests. Once there, in the `Source` field select `IP address`, type the public IP address assigned to your computer from your ISP and un-check the option `This is an IP address used in GCP.`. After that on the `Destination Endpoint` field select `VM instance` and select the VM instance where your Jenkins is deployed, for last type the `destination port` that would be 8080. When you run this test you will be able to see if there is any problem with your network path in GCP.

Comment: i did like you said,and result of configuration analysis was "Undetermined",i read about it in internet,for me it's really hard to understand where somethins went wrong.
Configuration analysis trace path was aborte,it says "Aborted because no valid source endpoint is derived from the input test request"
I execute cmd and write ipconfig /all to see my public IP,copy it and put in source endpoint,in Destination endpoint i put my External IP on VM,where i install jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Use the default [settings](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/initial-settings/), because `HTTP_HOST=127.0.0.1` locks you out:

```
HTTP_HOST=0.0.0.0
HTTP_PORT=8080
HTTPS_HOST=0.0.0.0
HTTPS_PORT=443
```

Listing to all interfaces with `0.0.0.0` is fine, but `HTTP_PORT` should be `-1`.

Comment: i got the same setting but it doesn't work anyway.And i dont understand why i should set -1 to http_port cuz it will disable it.

Comment: i put this in jenkins file,but it still dont want to work